# No signal after attempting to use DDU with Safe Mode

Tags: display, amd-radeon

My graphics card (Radeon RX 570) was stuck at 300Mhz for the memory clock all the time, and I read that using DDU to uninstall old drivers and then reinstall them would help to fix the issue.

Once I opened DDU, I was prompted to either "Launch" or "Reboot with Safe Mode." It was recommended to use Safe Mode, so I went with it. After pressing the button though, I have been unable to get a signal on any monitor with any cable.

I attempted to use the onboard graphics, but the same problem persisted. I cannot get a signal from there either. I am pretty sure this is due to the iGPU being disabled.

After I took out my GPU, I noticed my motherboard speaker gave its single beep. With the graphics card in, I noticed that it had stopped doing that a while ago.

I really need to know how I can get a display at the very least, even with the iGPU. If possible, I'd also like to know why my graphics card is not functioning the way it should. Several forums have said that DDU is not the culprit, but I am beginning to have doubts.

Thanks for any help in advance, let me know if there is any other information I should provide.

Specs:

CPU: i3-6100

RAM: 2x4GB

MOTHERBOARD: Gigabyte ga-h110m-a

GPU: Radeon RX 570

PSU: 500W

HDD: 1TB

Comment: Remove the CMOS battery; that should throw you back to the defaults, otherwise your going to have to come up with some way to boot to the first PCIe slot if your firmware is configured that way.  Next time DO NOT use DDU, seen more people screw up their systems, then even the amount of systems totaled by EasyBCD (another program you should never use)

Comment: Better solution: use the 9) CLR_CMOS (Clear CMOS Jumper) check your manual for for information

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what to do. I removed the CMOS battery to reset the BIOS to its default, enabled the iGPU, and the re-installed the drivers for my graphics card.